# Undesired shimmering effect using D3 to create adjacent rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm generating a musical waveform using D3 by pushing rectangles next to one another.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dML/

```
var data = [ 0.0534973, /* ...lots and lots of data... */ 0.290771];
data = data.filter(function(datum, index){
    return index % 3 == 0;
});

var width      = 340,
    height     = 70,
    svg        = d3
        .select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

svg
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data.map(function(datum){
        return (datum * height)/2;
    }))
    // .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i){
        return i * (width / data.length);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
        return (height /2) - d ;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d, i){
        return width / data.length;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d){
        return d*2;
    })
    .attr('fill', 'teal');
```

Does anyone know why the result ins't single, flat color as expected?  There is a kind of shimmering effect throughout.  This might be desirable, but regardless I'd like to know how it got there and how to get rid of it if I'm so inclined.

Comment: it appears to me that there are alternating bands of light and dark.  Is that what you mean by shimmering?  If so, it might be caused by the numerous borders of the rectangles

Comment: Yes, the alternating bands of light and dark are the undesired visual effect I'm referring to.  Any idea how to get rid of them and just have a single, solid color?

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of SVG rendering (or really, any vector graphics rendering). Suppose that you have two rects that meet 40% of the way into a pixel. Then the first rect will paint into that pixel with 40% opacity, and the second with 60% opacity, meaning that the pixel is only (40 + 0.6 * 60 =) 76% colored, even though logically it is 100% covered by colored shapes.

A fix for this is to define the graph as a single `<path>` object tracing out the top and bottom edges with no "cracks" like this between rects.

I'm not familiar with D3, but in ordinary Javascript:

```
var path = "M 0," + (height / 2);

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var x = (i + 1) * (width / data.length);
  var y = height / 2 - (data[i] * height)/2;
  path += " V " + y + " H " + x;
}

for(var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var x = i * (width / data.length);
  var y = height / 2 + (data[i] * height)/2;
  path += " V " + y + " H " + x;
}

path += " Z";
```

Comment: Interesting.  Any ideas as to how to get around this?

Comment: Great!  I'll give it that a shot.

Comment: This kind of artifacting is called a [Moiré Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

Comment: These artifacts are a result of web browsers not supporting [full-scene antialiasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). I filed a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35211) requesting this long ago; maybe it will happen eventually!

Comment: @mbostock: Fullscreen antialiasing works by rendering at a higher resolution and then scaling down. In some cases this might make this problem look less extreme, but it won't solve it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Russell's answer is a good one, though you'll end up with a monstrous path. This shouldn't be too much of a problem.

I encountered the same problem the other day when trying to make a bar chart of about 500 data points using very thin bars. The advantage of doing so is that it is much easier to make a mouseover that highlights an individual bar. In cases like this, I find that you have to use integer values for the widths and x positions.

For your example, setting the width and the interval to 1 completely fixes the problem while only making it about 10 percent shorter:

http://jsfiddle.net/s4dML/1/

```
.attr('x', function(d, i){
    return i;// * (width / data.length);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return (height /2) - d ;
})
.attr('width', function(d, i){
    return 1;
})
```

Of course, this not an extensible solution--just depends on your plans for the widget. I added a mouseover in the above example for demo purposes.

Comment: The only problem is that we want the waveform to be a constant length regardless of the number of data points, so this particular solution doesn't work for us.  But it sure is pretty.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you should accept the other solution. Nice use of D3.